# How to Bind a SQL Data Source value into a textbox in Asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

I have a SQL Data source which contains an Event ID. How will i bind its value to a textbox in a details view, so the user don't have to enter the ID as the ID will automatically be generated there. I dont know if this helps but the Event ID is passed through the link as well. E.g ../View_EventJoin.aspx?EventID={0}

What i tried is i made a form view using the sql Datasource and then deleted the "Event ID" field but the left the value. Then i copied this form view and deleted the textbox in the details view and inserted the form view. This made it look like what it should do but when someone tries to insert - the event Id will always be blank.

Comment: `textboxid.Text = Request.QueryString("EventID");` If you are passing `EventID` as your example

Comment: @Bharadwaj    the text box in a details View, so where would i write this code?

Comment: Add it in `Page_Load` event.

Comment: @Bharadwaj textboxid does not exist because the textbox is part of the details view. if i change this to a template i still only can make changes to TextBox1_TextChanged.

Comment: For `TextBox` inside `DetailsView`, add `Text` attribute as `Text = '<%# Request.QueryString("EventID") %>'`

Comment: @Bharadwaj When i try that i get another error- Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 

Compiler Error Message: CS1955: Non-invocable member 'System.Web.HttpRequest.QueryString' cannot be used like a method.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55430/discussion-between-user2775042-and-bharadwaj).